# Can we use JSTL in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jsp, reactjs, jstl

Is it possible to use **JSTL** (**JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library**) along with **ReactJS** and **JSP**?

**ReactJS** uses **JSX** (JSX is a syntactic extension to **Javascript**). Same way can it use and implement **JSTL** also. Though **ReactJS** is front end library and **JSP** is server side scripting, can it be achieved to a minimal extend?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, any extension in javascript is for the browser, so it's running at clien't side. While JSTL is a server side library.

> **The JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL)** is a collection of useful JSP tags which encapsulates core functionality common to many JSP applications. JSTL has support for common, structural tasks such as iteration and conditionals, tags for manipulating XML documents, internationalization tags, and SQL tags.

You can use it on the backend in the modern browser. You can also use it on the frontend for the client that has no javascript enabled. But it's rarely used today.